# List items iteration speed too slow when having another loop inside

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two list, one with all possible devices and another with just few devices. I need pass final list with this condition:
if  full list == one of the items in smaller list, make this item "active" too true, else leave it false.

I have no problem when working with full list >500 devices and small list >50, but when I have for example 2000 devices everything start to be too slow (on Google Pixel 2XL I need to wait about 6 seconds to job finish).

Question: how can I increase this loop speed?

What I have done so far:

```
devicesList.forEach { device ->

            device.selected = false

            items.forEach { it ->
                if(it.id == device.id){
                    device.selected = true
                }
            }
```

But this is too slow for larger data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is make `selected = true` if a device's `id` exists in the list `items`, you can get all the ids of `items` like this:

```
val ids = items.map { it.id }
```

and then loop through `devices`:

```
devicesList.forEach { it.selected = it.id in ids }
```

Comment: Hello, very nice solution! Thank you ! Also, I combined this with @Frencesc suggestion move this logic to background task and it's work like a charm, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You can speed it up a bit by not using `forEach`, which uses an interator and instead use a for loop. You can also break once you locate your `id`, assuming they are unique

```
for (i in 0 until devicesList.size) {
    val device = devicesList[i]
    for (j in 0 until items.size) {
         val item = items[j]
         if (item.id == device.id) {
             device.selected = true
             break
         }
     }
}
```

Assuming your `id`s are unique, you could also make a duplicate of the `items` list and drop those that have been located, so each loop is shorter, like this

```
val copy = items.toMutableList()
for (i in 0 until devicesList.size) {
    val device = devicesList[i]
    for (j in 0 until copy.size) {
        val item = copy[j]
        if (item.id == device.id) {
            device.selected = true
            copy.remove(item)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

You could also consider creating a map where the `key` is your `id` so you do not have to loop and instead you retrieve the item by `id` directly. You have to weight the cost of creating the map in the first place.

```
val map = items.associateBy { it.id }
for (i in 0 until devicesList.size) {
    val device = devicesList[i]
    device.selected = map[device.id] != null
}
```

Besides this, you should also move your logic to a background thread and wait for it to complete.

Comment: Hello, and hank you ! For my problem @forpas solution was good enough, but I also used your idea to move all logic to background thread, this helped a lot!